# For some reason on the @overide part it says 'method does not override method from it's superclass'. How do I resove this?

Tags: java, android, android-studio-2.1

For some reason on the @overide part it says 'method does not override method from it's superclass'. How do I resove this?

```js
public class Main6Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button buttonChoose;
    private Button buttonUpload;

    private ImageView imageView;

    private EditText editTextName;

    private Bitmap bitmap;

    private int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;

    private String UPLOAD_URL = "http://simplifiedcoding.16mb.com/VolleyUpload/upload.php";

    private String KEY_IMAGE = "image";
    private String KEY_NAME = "name";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main6);

        buttonChoose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonChoose);
        buttonUpload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUpload);

        editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        buttonChoose.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonUpload.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return encodedImage;

    private void uploadImage() {
        //Showing the progress dialog
        final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Uploading...", "Please wait...", false, false);
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, UPLOAD_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String s) {
                        //Disimissing the progress dialog
                        loading.dismiss();
                        //Showing toast message of the response
                        Toast.makeText(Main6Activity.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                        //Dismissing the progress dialog
                        loading.dismiss();

                        //Showing toast
                        Toast.makeText(Main6Activity.this, volleyError.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                //Converting Bitmap to String
                String image = getStringImage(bitmap);

                //Getting Image Name
                String name = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();

                //Creating parameters
                Map<String, String> params = new Hashtable<String, String>();

                //Adding parameters
                params.put(KEY_IMAGE, image);
                params.put(KEY_NAME, name);

                //returning parameters
                return params;
            }
        };


        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);


        //Adding request to the queue
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    private void showFileChooser() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            Uri filePath = data.getData();
            try {
                //Getting the Bitmap from Gallery
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
                //Setting the Bitmap to ImageView
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v == buttonChoose) {
            showFileChooser();
        }

        if (v == buttonUpload) {
            uploadImage();


        }
    }


}
```

Thankyou and help would be appreciated.
For some reason on the @overide part it says 'method does not override method from it's superclass'. How do I resove this?

Comment: you haven't implemented onClickListener interface that's why you have that message

Answer (score 0):

It means your method has its declaration imperfect, maybe missing some parts. Look to which method the error is been raised and search for the pattern declaration of this obligatory method on the web.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the "does not override" complain is against the onClick() method. The AppCompatActivity does not have such method. Your Main6Activity class needs to implement the View.OnClickListener interface as follows:

```
public class Main6Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
```